# Does memsql support Full Outer Join?

Tags: outer-join, full-outer-join, singlestore

I wanted to have a full outer join in memsql. Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON A.id  = B.id
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/ref/SELECT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that MemSQL does *not* have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` syntax.  However, you should be able to simulate a full outer join in MemSQL using a combination of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` `OUTER JOIN` operations:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.id
WHERE ISNULL(A.id)
```

[image]

The first `SELECT` covers the orange area, namely matching records between `A` and `B` along with records in `A` which do not match to anything in `B`.  The second query obtains only records in `B` which do not match to anything in `A`.  Using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` ensures that duplicates are not removed.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could update the link that is no longer valid. Thanks!